# Grails JQuery PeriodicUpdater

Tags: jquery, grails

I want to use a periodic Updater in jQuery to update a chat div periodically. Therefore I include the jQuery library in the layout file with:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

From the page http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/ I downloaded the periodicalupdater plugin for jquery and linked it to my gsp page:

```
<g:javascript src="jquery.periodicalupdater.js"/>
```

On my page I use this script to start the periodicalUpdater:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.PeriodicalUpdater({
            url : 'URL'
        }, function(data) {
            var myHtml = 'The data returned from the server was: ' + data + '';
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, that the URL isn't even called. I get the following error, when looking at the browser console:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.PeriodicalUpdater')
```

Edit: I solved the problem. The periodicUpdater Plugin was just loaded before the jquery. But now I have another problem. I write the following lines in my code:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" /><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.PeriodicalUpdater({url : 'http://localhost:8080/PROJECT/comment/ajax_list/1'},
        function(data){$('#comment').empty().append(data);});
    });
</script>
```

I want to have the URL without the localhost, because I want to load it in production mode, too...

Comment: looks like your link is broken.

Comment: which link? the jQuery link? Or the periodicUpdater. Hmm, they´re both in place.

Comment: I solved the problem. You were right. The problem was, that the periodic updater was loaded before the jquery. But now I have another problem. See my edited post.

Comment: I was actually referring to the link to the blog post, which now works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my layout file I have the following:

```
<script>
    contextPath = "${request.contextPath}";
</script>
```

And then updating your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.PeriodicalUpdater({url : contextPath + '/comment/ajax_list/1'},
        function(data){$('#comment').empty().append(data);});
    });
</script>
```